# Modelling seats of a table in a social game

Tags: c#, design, initialization, lazy-initialization

Assume we want to model a table where players can sit down to get together to play a game (card games, dice games, ...). Assume a few properties associated with each seat

```
class Seat
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public double Money { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Say the Table is simply modelled as

```
class Table
{
    public Seat[] Seats = new Seat[6];
}
```

And I want to represent empty seats. Is it a better practise to have `Seats[i] = null` or adding a Flag / Enumeration / ... that indicates the Seat is empty and all properties are invalid? Like `if (Seats[i].SeatState != Seatstate.Empty) { ... }`

Comment: What does the seat represent? Does it represent a seat (i.e. a chair), or a seated player (i.e. the person on the chair)? Based on the content of your `Seat` class, I'm inclined to read this as a seated player rather than a seat by itself. Naming matters, and it helps make things clearer as to what your expectations of the code's behavior should be.

Comment: @Flater I think it's `Seat` like a spot, so it's likely a `Chair` (or position) around a `Table`. Not a `Player` state.

Comment: @Laiv: If that were the case, it seems counterintuitive for this seat class to have a money property attached to it. Hence my question to ask for elaboration.

Comment: In one or another design, `Money` seems out of the place.

Comment: @Flater It is indeed a spot at a table from which a player can stand-up and sit-down. I added `Money` directly to the seat to not further complicate the example. I could indeed instead use a Player object

Comment: @Benj: Brevity does not always make things easier. The lack of separation between a seat and a player can lead to different conclusions being made on how to handle the overly terse structure.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Special Case Pattern? (aka Null Object Pattern)?

Comment: @Laiv That sounds interesting. Will have a look at it.

Comment: Null object pattern is a powerful one for this sort of application. It is particularly powerful if you also go with an immutable object architecture. That is, a change to the world is not modeled by *mutating a variable* but by *creating a new immutable world that has the change*. That sounds expensive, but if you are clever you can re-use most of the original state; after all, it is immutable!

Answer (score 3):

A `Seat` should know whether or not it **is occupied**. Simply because someone **joins or leaves the game** doesn't mean you need a `new Seat()`. The player has just **vacated** that spot at the table.

That being said, the `PlayerId` and `Money` properties are currently value types, meaning they will always have a value. In this case it appears they do *not* always have a value, so the first change should be to make those properties nullable (the second change I would make is to use `decimal` as the data type for the `Money` property).

Currently everything in both `Table` and `Seat` is public. In the very least you want to enforce some [encapsulation](https://stackify.com/oop-concept-for-beginners-what-is-encapsulation/), and make the setters for your properties private. My first sentence has some bold face words and phrases, which you can use to guide your design of the `Seat` class:

- is occupied
- joins or leaves the game
- vacated

These give you some of the basic operations that can be performed on a `Seat`. The `Seat` class should have a property that returns whether or not this particular seat is currently occupied. When both `PlayerId` and `Money` are null, then `seat.IsOccupied` should return false.

This leads us to discover our first [class invariant](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/355638/118878): when `PlayerId` is not null, then `Money` should not be null as well. The setters for both properties need to be private. Something needs to ensure when a `Seat` becomes **occupied** that both player and money have values. We need a public method on the Seat class called `Occupy` that takes both values: `public void Occupy(int playerId, decimal money)`. Here we can use the Type System in C# to ensure both values are not null by virtue of the fact they are both value types.

Now when you create a `new Seat()` the player Id and money properties are both `null` and `seat.IsOccupied` returns false. After calling `seat.Occupy(45, 1200.00m)` both properties are set, and then `seat.IsOccupied` returns true.

Finally, when someone leaves the game, they **vacate** the seat. The `seat.Vacate()` method should set both `PlayerId` and `Money` to null, which will cause `seat.IsOccupied` to return false.

```
var seat = new Seat(); // Create vacant seat

seat.Occupy(45, 50.00m);

// Play game

seat.Vacate(); // Spouse calls. Kids are going crazy. Time to go home.
```

But we still have a problem. Calling `seat.Vacate()` makes the player (and their money) disappear. While this works out great for players that owe the House money (or maybe it doesn't...) players that still have money do not want to blink out of existence simply because they left the game. You need a `Player` class to encapsulate the player Id and money properties. So a `Seat` really only needs a `Player` in order to determine if it `IsOccupied`:

```
var player = new Player(45, 50.00m);
var blackJackTable = new Table();
var texasHoldemTable = new Table();

blackJackTable.Seats[0].Occupy(player);
Console.Writeline(blackJackTable.Seats[0].IsOccupied); // Prints "True"
blackJackTable.Seats[0].Vacate();

texasHoldemTable.Seats[2].Occupy(player);
texasHoldemTable.Seats[2].Vacate(); // Spouse calls. Kids are going crazy. Time to go home.
```

Now a `Player` can occupy and vacate a seat, and then transfer their winnings to another game.

But we *still* have a problem. You need to know which seat is available when joining a table. The `Table` class needs some encapsulation as well. The `Table` class should expose a public method allowing you to join the table. In fact, `public Seat Join(Player newPlayer)` would be a great method to add to the Table class. That encapsulates logic for joining the table. It returns a `Seat` which at a later time the player can choose to `Vacate()`. By exposing a public boolean property on `Table` called `IsFull` that returns true if all `Seats` are occupied, code outside the `Table` class does not need access to the Seats array. The Seats array should be completely hidden. Make `Seats` a private, read-only property. This is called [information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding), and is another fundamental concept of object oriented programming.